# Emulators are found but USB are not?

Tags: android

I've just installed windows 10 after my old version crashed and i installed android studio.
Every thing is fine but USB devices are not found but emulators are found.
However i find my SD card and my phone in Copmuter and i have access to files, 
i can see my phone from computer but not from android studio
What i tried:
1.I have my phone USB debugging.
2.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwyCx.png)I also made sure that my phone is recognized from device manager.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You probabelly don't installed ADB driver yet? If it is the case you can get it from [here](http://adbdriver.com/)

**UPDATE**: if already installed, try by changing deployment target, go to *RUN -> Edit configurations* and under *Deployment target options* choose *USB Device*

**UPDATE 2**: For Cyanogemod, follow [these steps](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/93453)

Comment: It gives me an error "No target device found." at left bottom corner

Comment: Try by changing your device usb connexion mode (MTP to PTP)

Comment: unfortunately, not working too.
I have tried all of them.
I have installed android studio twice in order to solve this problem but nothing works.

Comment: Do you have any ideas?

Comment: A lot of reasons can cause this issue. Did you tried with another device? Changing the usb cable? using USB 2.0 port instead of 3.0?

Comment: Did you install Google USB Device? https://developer.android.com/studio/run/win-usb

Comment: I think the problem is because of using cyanogenmod  system in my device but the point is that it was working very well before installing new windows.
I tried another device through USB and worked.

Comment: It worked 
i followed these steps and converted it to PTP